# How to send integer parameter to RabbitMQ?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, python-asyncio

How to send integer parameter to rabbitMQ with aiormq.
With this:

```
async def save_to_db(number: int):
    # Perform connection
    connection = await aiormq.connect("amqp://guest:guest@" + rabbitmqHost + "/")

    # Creating a channel
    channel = await connection.channel()

    # Sending the message
    await channel.basic_publish(number, routing_key=queueName)
```

I am getting:

```
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

I tried to cast it to string and then it worked.
I need it to be integer to insert it to database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`basic_publish` wants bytes](https://github.com/mosquito/aiormq/blob/89859576cae8e04e29c9dd344e828e3320de16a0/aiormq/channel.py#L527), not arbitrary values. You'll need to [encode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes) your value (and then [decode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes) it when it's read from the queue).

```
# Sending the message
await channel.basic_publish(number.to_bytes(2, byte_order="big"))

# Receiving the message
async def on_Message(message):
    number = int.from_bytes(message.body, byte_order="big")
```